# How to retrieve the values of "Total"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase database structure. 
[image]

I want to fetch the values of "Total" of all children of "Bill". I have tried to fetch the data but my code is not working. Here is my code.

```
 DatabaseReference billReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bill");
        billReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    fetchCount++;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+keys[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String temp = ds.child(keys[i]).child("Breakfast").child("11-2018").child("Total").getValue().toString();
                    breakfastBills.add(names[i] + " : " + temp);
                    i++;
                }
                if (fetchCount == 4) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(bill_details_manager.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Bill Details for Breakfast");
                    builder.setItems(breakfastBills.toArray(new String[breakfastBills.size()]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        }
                    });
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
```

What is wrong with this code ?

Comment: looks like you are trying to get child "BreakFast" but the db has "Breakfast"

Comment: @Quinn, Not working with "Breakfast".

Comment: @AbbasAli `Breakfast` node can have more children than the one is in your database (11-2018) right now? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, yes but in my case there is only one child (Total).

Comment: @AbbasAli And there will only one or you think that can be more?

Comment: @AlexMamo, Only one

Comment: @AbbasAli Will it be helful for you, if I'll provide an answer that implies a change in your database stucture?

Comment: @AlexMamo, Yes please...

Comment: @AbbasAli Do you really need that `11-2018` node?

Comment: @Alex, yes it is according to every month

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184155/discussion-between-abbas-ali-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: @Alex. Yes next child will be 12-2018

Comment: So I have asked if there will be other children and you said no. You said that it will be only one. So please edit your question and make it more clear and responde after that.

Comment: @Alex, Right now there is only one child but when the month changes it will have more than one

Comment: Alright. So you want a total of all `Total` fields **just** under `Breakfast`, right?

Comment: I want to get only values of all "Total" fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    DatabaseReference billRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    billRef.child("Bill").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot allValueSnap) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: allValueSnap.getChildren()){
                String key = snapshot.getKey();
                if (key != null) {
                    billRef.child("Bill").child(key).child("Breakfast").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot keySnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot dateSnapshot:keySnapshot.getChildren()){
                                String keyDate = dateSnapshot.getKey();
                                long totalValue =(long) keySnapshot.child(keyDate).child("Total").getValue();
                                Log.i("totalBreakFast","STotal: "+String.valueOf(totalValue));
                                breakfastBills.add(totalValue);
                            }
                            if(!keySnapshot.exists()){
                                Log.i("totalBreakFast","NoData: ");
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This code is getting all values of "Total".